# RAM incompatibility issue in Lenovo Z570

Tags: windows, memory, lenovo-laptop

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit on Lenovo Z570. I have already 6GB DDR3 RAM(4GB transcend + 2GB Ramaxel). Now, I wanted to make RAM upto 8GB.

[image]

[image]

So, I have purchased corsair 4GB DDR3 SODIMM Memory (CMSO4GX3M1A1600C11).

And tried to put it in place of 2GB RAM. But my laptop is not booting even.
I have also removed both previous RAMs and installed newly purchased single RAM only but my laptop is still not booting.

So, what should I understand from this? Does this 4GB corsair RAM incompatible with Lenovo Z570 and have I wasted my money? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: If the original configuration is not working then the reason your device isn't booting isn't caused by an incompatibility with the new memory.

Comment: @Ramhound, no, no. I don't have any issues with 6GB DDR3 RAM(4GB transcend + 2GB Ramaxel). It's running perfectly.

Comment: If thats the case, then yes, the memory would appear to be incompatible.  The frequency is higher then your existing memory.  It typically isn't a problem but in this case it is due to the age of the hardware.  The memory you purchased is twice as fast as the original memory.  Frequency is faster but the timing was a great deal different which is likely the problem.

Comment: ok...but then why laptop is not booting even. I mean it's not giving that F2 option start screen even? What would be the reason behind that?

Comment: What do you mean?  The memory is running a stock frequency faster then your laptop can support, and your laptop does not have the functionality, to down clock the frequency.

Comment: I'm not getting your point. Would you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo z570 supports up to 1333GHz RAM (have a look on 31 page of this [hardware manual](https://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/UserGuide/en/User's%20guides%20and%20manuals/Z370&Z470&Z570/Lenovo%20Z370Z470Z570%20Hardware%20Maintenance%20Manual%20V1.0.pdf)), but you've purchased RAM with [1600GHz](http://www.corsair.com/en/corsair-memory-4gb-ddr3-sodimm-memory-cmso4gx3m1a1600c11), hence the reason why your new RAM does not let you boot your laptop.

I also do not quite understand how you were able to run on RAM with a different capacity - 4GB+2GB. As an owner of the same laptop such configuration never worked for me. I've upgraded my z570 from 2x2GB to [2x4GB Corsair 1333GHz CMSO8GX3M2A1333C9](http://www.corsair.com/en/cmso8gx3m2a1333c9) and everything works perfect.

My advice would be to return the RAM if it is still possible and exchange it to something with a following GHz range  800, 1066 or 1333.